# Accessing Xml Element Attribute in a xsd class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd2code

I have a generated c# class from xsd. when I want to give value to the elements

```
result res = new result();
res.feed = "123132";
```

// This works
res.data here I can not find id and value, how can I do for instance `res.data.id="something"`

I have an xml :

```
<result>
    <feed></feed>
    <status></status>
    <data>
        <id></id>
        <value></value> 
        <id></id> 
        <value></value> 
    </data>
</result>
```

that generates this xsd :

```
  <xs:element name="result">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="feed"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="status"/>
        <xs:element name="data">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and with xsd.exe I have generated the class for it

```
public partial class result {

    private string feedField;

    private string statusField;

    private resultData dataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string feed {
        get {
            return this.feedField;
        }
        set {
            this.feedField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public resultData data {
        get {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class resultData {

    private string[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("id", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("value", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public string[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    id,

    /// <remarks/>
    value,
}
```

Comment: What options did you use when you ran xsd.exe?

Comment: I chose xsd.exe /c fine.xsd

Comment: I think part of the problem is the xml structure.  You can repeat team, but there is nothing grouping id and value together.

Comment: but <data></data> is grouping them

Comment: @lol I believe tdbeckett means a subgrouping like `<data><sub><id>123</id><value>abc</value></sub><sub><id>456</id><value>def</value></sub></data>` if you meant to have id-value pairs.  What you have right now would allow you to have just ids or just values and doesn't require them to be in any particular order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to do the following

```
res.data = new resultData();
res.data.ItemsElementName = new [] 
{ 
    ItemsChoiceType.id,
    ItemsChoiceType.value,
    ItemsChoiceType.id,
    ItemsChoiceType.value,
};
res.data.Items = new [] 
{ 
    "id 1",
    "value 1",
    "id 2",
    "value 2",
};
```

Basically you have to set each array to contain the type and corresponding value.  When you create the arrays they should have the same length and the type and value should be in the same position.

However if you want id-value pairs you should rethink the structure of your XML as currently it will allow you to just put in ids or just values and does not guarantee order or that there will be the same number of each.  Maybe something like the following is more like want you want.

```
<result>
    <feed></feed>
    <status></status>
    <data>
        <dataItem>
            <id></id>
            <value></value> 
        </dataItem>
        <dataItem>
            <id></id> 
            <value></value> 
        </dataItem>
    </data>
</result>
```

Comment: res.data.id = "jhgjh" give me the error can not implicitely convert 'string' to 'ItemsChoiceType[]'

Comment: @lol Yeah, I've updated to reflect how the `resultData` class actually works.

Comment: in fact when I put it in try catch gives me the error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @lol Make sure to create a `resultData` first.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried to do this : 
res.data = new resultData();
                res.data.ItemsElementName = new[] { ItemsChoiceType.id };
                res.data.Items = new[] { "something" };
                res.data.ItemsElementName = new[] { ItemsChoiceType.value };
                res.data.Items = new[] { "sth" };
                res.data.ItemsElementName = new[] { ItemsChoiceType.id };
                res.data.Items = new[] { "xxxx" };
                res.data.ItemsElementName = new[] { ItemsChoiceType.value };
                res.data.Items = new[] { "yyyyyy" };

Comment: after XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(result));
                using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, res);
                    xmlString = textWriter.ToString();
                }

Comment: There is Only the last value!
<result>
<success>true</success>
<feedbackToken>123132</feedbackToken>
<data>
<value>yyyyyy</value>
</data>
 </result>

Comment: I'll update to show you how to add multiple ids and values by putting them all into one array that you assign to the properties.

Comment: but what if I need to have all these id and values under data?

Comment: as in xsd also we have <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">